# How can I use google maps api to display a house (not street view)? Like instantstreetview.com

Tags: google-maps, maps

I'm making a page that displays information on a house the user looks up. I need to show a picture of the house. When I use google's map api, I enter the gps coordinates, but it defaults to the street view. How can I default to the property, similar to instantstreetview.com? Thanks!

Comment: please take some time to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, if you have some attempted code you would like to share, please modify your post so we can address a specific programming question rather than a how to generic question. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy!

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=37.4224764,-122.0842499&fov=90&pitch=10&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I just tried it with the lat/lng for my own home, and it worked just fine.

You

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was trying to do it through js, but an image tag will work too! Thanks so much!